# Does the world altitude on objects affects its shader output?

Tags: mesh, shaders

I'm making a character and putting it an environment. I had used the BlenderGIS addon to get the location which will affect the height of the mesh. The objects are attached to an armature inheriting its transformation properties. The eyes are compose of two separate meshes that are less than an inch apart with each having its own material. On the outer mesh is a glossy shader, and the inner one has a Principled BDSF shader. The following screenshots are eyes in local mode from the character:

[image]

*At default coordinates (0, 0, 0)*

[image]

*At 463 ft on the z axis*

This is first time that I saw this happening in Blender. I had adjusted the camera and render settings but it doesn't do anything when I changed the character's altitude. Is this a bug in Blender because I've tried without the addon and it was still doing the same thing. Does anyone know what's causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

World space altitude (Z position) does not do anything special.  Materials can affect things (especially if using object coords with something armature deformed); and of course, moving one thing but not everything can change things (because then you're lighting from a different angle, or reflecting things with a different relative position.)

But what you're probably seeing are errors related to precision from placing your geometry + camera far from the world origin.  Z axis in particular doesn't mean anything special, but distance from origin does.  It shouldn't, but it does.  See https://developer.blender.org/T43835 .

I can't say that for certain without seeing your file though.  It would be easy for a material you're using to be based on world position in some way.  Possibly, in a way that isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Interesting reference.. I'm naively wondering why Cycles would be founded in World, not Camera, space.

Comment: @RobinBetts That is exactly what I wondered out loud in that bug report (or one linked to it) :)  I don't know enough about ray tracing to have any idea myself.

Comment: I've read the thread in the link and have moved my scene much closer to the world origin. The render results came out just as expected. Maybe camera distance is a limit in ray-tracing.